# Thick Client memory encryption

Tags: encryption, algorithm

I came across a thick client application recently. The application temporarily stores sensitive data (like username and password) in clear text in memory and the data is flushed once the user logs out or the application is closed.

Inorder to increase the security implementation of the application **is there any technique where I could encrypt the sensitive data stored in memory?** so that data are encrypted whenever application memory is dumped.

Please suggest some resources for implementation.

Comment: I think the answer is to not store this data in memory.

Comment: @shroeder As far as my understanding, all application consumes memory and temporarily stores/writes data into memory (RAM) until it is over written by another data. Can you explain how could we avoid sensitive data from not getting stored/written in memory?

Comment: There's a difference between having data in memory and storing data in memory. If you want to somehow encrypt the working memory, then you still need to decrypt it and store the plaintext in working memory, too.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain what you want to protect against. If you flush data in memory when you are done with it, then you mitigate most issues.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the solutions to this problem are:

- Don't store sensitive data in memory (could be dificult to achieve in some cases);
- Encrypt data stored in memory (raises the problem of managing/securing encryption keys);
- Minimise the time sensitive data is stored in memory (i.e. scrub [overwrite] it as soon as it is used, then find a method to obtain it again if needed);

For the purpose of authentication, the password is required once to verify the stored hash, after that it won't be needed any more until the next login.

Memory based attacks are relatively complex and usually require physical access, so keep that in mind to assess your business risk.

Above all, make sure whatever is left in memory (even temporarily) or on disk that is sensitive data cannot be reused elsewhere (i.e. on another thick client) - this is where the big risk comes in. Static keys shared across multiple (all?) devices, accounts that work elsewhere, shared local passwords and local secrets, private keys, etc.